# How can I find the World Seed of an online multiplayer Valheim Server?

Tags: valheim

I discovered http://valheim-map.world/ yesterday and it’s really neat! However, the seed extraction tool provided only works for games saved on my own, local computer. I do most of my Viking-ing on a multiplayer dedicated server with a few friends.

Is there any way that I can see the world seed for the dedicated server I play on, so that I can plug it in to this website, or, for example, to spin up a duplicate world on my home machine?

Answer (score 6):

The seed is available in the `.fwl` file with the same name as your world. This answer will be Linux specific, but it should be very similar for Windows and/or visible in text editors like Notepad++ or worst case a hex editor.

Given `your_world` you should have a `your_world.db`, `your_world.db.old` (backup), and `your_world.fwl`. The `.fwl` file is very small and only contains your world name and the seed of that world.

Looking at it simply with `cat` like pure plaintext will give you some garbage as well, but the seed (in this example `u6jEVeytUb`) is visible:

```
# cat foo.fwl
foo
u6jEVeytUbҖ���K�����
```

It's easier to see it with something like `xxd` if you follow the data on the right, it will be right after your world name:

```
# xxd foo.fwl
(...)
00000010: 450a 7536 6a45 5665 7974 5562 19d2 96a6  E.u6jEVeytUb....
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^- here!
```

Comment: This solution unfortunately only works if you own the world, but does not work when you join a world of another player/server. OP asked specifically about the seed of a dedicated server.

Comment: ”Dedicated” does not mean “owned by someone else”. In this case OP specifically mentioned he plays with friends. Considering what a seed actually is it makes sense having access to the world makes it a lot easier, if you don’t your best hope would be if the client exposes it but I don’t see a reason why it would.

Answer (score 5):

This information can be gained from the Player Log file!

To retrieve your multiplayer games world seed:

1. Start up Valheim
2. From the main menu, click the button labelled `Show Player.log` hidden away at the bottom left corner of the screen. This will open a folder in Windows Explorer; minimize that and come back to Valheim for now, we'll double back to this in a minute.
3. Join your multiplayer server as normal. (Start Game -> Start->Join Game, yadda yadda. You know this.)
4. Once you've loaded into the game world that you want the world seed for, it's time to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> back to the Valheim AppData folder that was opened up by that player.log button.
5. We want to open the text file named `Player.log`, or, depending on your windows settings, it may show up as simply `Player`.
6. In that document, you'll want to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or scroll down and look for the string `Initializing world generator seed:`. Your seed will appear right after that*. Remember, world seeds are case sensitive!

*<sub>`Initializing World Generator Seed:` may show up in the log file more than once, however, the first time it will appear without a string of characters following it. This is the world generator seed for the menu. Scroll down to where you see it a second time for the game world you've just loaded into.</sub>

Comment: An anonymous user has suggested an edit to this post, reporting that a recent update has removed that information from the log and the only information we get is a steamid and IP of the server we are connecting to. I have voted to reject this edit on the grounds that it is an attempt to reply to your post, however you may want to consider looking into the given issue and updating your answer if necessary.

Comment: A registered user has also suggested an edit to this post, reporting for the second time that a recent update has removed that information from the log and the only information we get is a steamid and IP of the server we are connecting to. Again I have voted to reject this edit on the grounds that it is an attempt to reply to your post. You should really look into this, because it seems like this info may now be incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Use **[Cheat Engine](https://www.cheatengine.org/)**. This is taken from a [comment by Reddit user ‘madpata’](https://www.reddit.com/r/valheim/comments/lg6hkp/is_there_a_way_to_check_your_map_seed/gudxzr8/):

> Sadly, the Valheim developers removed that log entry. Probably to stop
> people from using [this tool](https://valheim-map.world/) to get
> trader/loot positions.
>
> However, there is another, but way more complicated way to get the
> seed: Using Cheat Engine. Be warned that you probably need a bit of
> experience with Cheat Engine to get this to work.
>
> (There's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIhBq9AMNdE) of
> this process available)
>
> - Open the valheim process
> - Mono -> Activate Mono features
> - Mono -> Dissect Mono
> - Search for class "World"
> - Right click on the "World" class and use "Find instances"
> - You'll get multiple results and only one is the one you want. Use the current values of an instance to judge if it's valid or not.
>
>   - `m_worldGenVersion` should be 1
>   - `m_menu`, `m_loadError` and `m_versionError` were all 0 for my instance.
> - Double click on the entry containing `m_seedName`. The "Memory Viewer" will open.
> - Right click on the bottom half of the memory viewer and click on "Goto address"
> - Enter the address that is pointed to by `m_seedName` and hit enter.
> - Your seed starts at that address + offset of 0x14 (<- hexadecimal) and is 20 bytes long. Ignore every other character (the '.' dots).
> - Profit

Video using Cheat Engine to access the seed of a multiplayer server if you are not the host:

Comment: Just wanted to say that I'm doing this after the Mistlands update and I found the seed under `m_worldGenVersion=2` world instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this on a linux server to read out the seed of your *.fwl file. If its called world.fwl in example:

```
(head -c$(od -j$(od -j8 -N1 -An -t u1) -N1 -An -t u1);echo)<world.fwl
```

Comment: This would require access to the machine the server is on. This questions asks how to find the seed of other people's worlds.

Comment: In fact, this question asks how to get the world seed of the dedicated server he plays on with friends. Valheim is a PvE game, which is mostly played in closed groups to prevent griefing. Therefore, it is very likely that one of his friends has administrative access to the server. This questions does not explicitly asks how to find the seed of other people's worlds.

Comment: If he doesnt have access to the server himself, he can still ask the admin to look it up for him. Even if it doesnt help OP, it might help others who came here by googling for the headline or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Only if circumstance allows it, of course: Ask the server admin for the world seed.

Answer (score -3):

Using a website called Valheim World Generator, which is found [here](https://valheim-map.world/getseed.html), you can easily extract your world's seed. Simply just drag the .FWL file into the page.

Comment: This is a repeat of the information in the first sentence of the question. Completely useless answer.

Comment: this actually does answer the question. You can simply upload the fwl file from the save game location `%appdata%\..\LocalLow\IronGate\Valheim`

Comment: @Eonasdan in the context of the question, the user doesn't have access to the save file, since they are talking about multiplayer servers that they don't run.